# downloading entries from mysql database over multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a very annoying issue with code I am working on in xcode for iOS, and it is driving me crazy!

This will take a lot of code explanation, as I need to include a lot of code.

I had a `viewcontroller` working, connecting to an online `mysql` database, and populating a `tableview`. This was all working great.

I then had to duplicate this code, as I want to download from another database and populate a mapview using co-ordinates from another mysql database.

`Screen5ViewController.h / Screen5ViewController.m` are the files for the `viewcontroller` with the `tableview`.

`ShopTable.h / ShopTable.m` is the code that handles the downloading of the data from the database.

This was all working.

`Screen2ViewController.h / Screen2ViewController.m / MapTable.h / MapTable.m` are the files I duplicated to download from the other database to populate the `mapview`.

This doesnt work at all, and doesnt even call the method `("NSLog(@"map table called...");")` - so it doesnt even try to download the data.

I dont understand why this method isnt even called?

The code compiles and runs with no errors and no warnings.

Any help anyone can give would be very much appreciated. I have spent so much time looking over this code and trying everything I can think of!

Screen5ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ShopTable.h"

@interface Screen5ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ShopTableProtocol> {
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *shopTableView;

@end
```

Screen5ViewController.m

```
#import "Screen5ViewController.h"

@interface Screen5ViewController () {
ShopTable *_shopTable;
NSArray *_feedItems;
}
@end

@implementation Screen5ViewController

@synthesize

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Screen 5";

// Set this view controller object as the delegate and data source for the table view
self.shopTableView.delegate = self;
self.shopTableView.dataSource = self;

// Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
_feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];

// Create new ShopTable object and assign it to _shopTable variable
_shopTable = [[ShopTable alloc] init];

// Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
_shopTable.delegate = self;

// Call the download items method of the home model object
[_shopTable downloadItems2];
}

-(void)itemsDownloaded2:(NSArray *)items {
// This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems = items;

// Reload the table view
[self.shopTableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of feed items (initially 0)
return _feedItems.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Retrieve cell
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"shopTableCell";
UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

// Get the location to be shown
Location2 *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

// Get references to labels of cell

myCell.textLabel.text = item.name;
myCell.detailTextLabel.text = item.address;

return myCell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

ShopTable.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ShopTableProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)itemsDownloaded2:(NSArray *)items;
@end

@interface ShopTable : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ShopTableProtocol> delegate;
- (void)downloadItems2;
@end

@interface Location2 : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@end
```

ShopTable.m

```
#import "ShopTable.h"

@interface ShopTable() {
NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
}
@end

@implementation ShopTable

- (void)downloadItems2 {
NSLog(@"shop table called...");

// Download the json file
NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/shop.php"];

// Create the request
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

// Create the NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// Initialize the data object
_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the newly downloaded data
[_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// Create an array to store the locations
NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

// Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Location2 *newLocation = [[Location2 alloc] init];
    newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"title"];
    newLocation.address = jsonElement[@"description"];
    newLocation.latitude = jsonElement[@"Latitude"];
    newLocation.longitude = jsonElement[@"Longitude"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}

// Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
if (self.delegate) {
    [self.delegate itemsDownloaded2:_locations];
}
}

@end

@implementation Location2
@end
```

Screen2ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapTable.h"

@interface Screen2ViewController : UIViewController <MapTableProtocol> {
}

@end
```

Screen2ViewController.m

```
#import "Screen2ViewController.h"

@interface Screen2ViewController () {
MapTable *_mapTable;
NSArray *_feedItems1;
}
@end

@implementation Screen2ViewController

@synthesize

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"Screen 2";

NSLog(@"1"); // This is called fine!

// Create array object and assign it to _feedItems variable
_feedItems1 = [[NSArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"2"); // This is called fine!

// Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
_mapTable.delegate = self;

NSLog(@"3"); // This is called fine!

// Call the download items method of the home model object
[_mapTable downloadItems];
}

NSLog(@"4"); // This is called fine!

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items {
// This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

// Set the downloaded items to the array
_feedItems1 = items;

NSLog(@"%lu locations downloaded ok!", (unsigned long)_feedItems1.count);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

MapTable.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol MapTableProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items;
@end

@interface MapTable : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MapTableProtocol> delegate;
- (void)downloadItems;
@end

@interface Location : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end
```

MapTable.m

```
#import "MapTable.h"

@interface MapTable() {
NSMutableData *_downloadedData1;
}
@end

@implementation MapTable

- (void)downloadItems {
NSLog(@"map table called..."); // THIS CODE NEVER GETS CALLED??!!

// Download the json file
NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/map.php"];

// Create the request
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

// Create the NSURLConnection
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// Initialize the data object
_downloadedData1 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the newly downloaded data
[_downloadedData1 appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// Create an array to store the locations
NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData1 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

// Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];

    // Create a new location object and set its props to JsonElement properties
    Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
    newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"firstname"];
    newLocation.latitude = jsonElement[@"mylatitude"];
    newLocation.longitude = jsonElement[@"mylongitude"];

    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:newLocation];
}

// Ready to notify delegate that data is ready and pass back items
if (self.delegate) {
    [self.delegate itemsDownloaded:_locations];
}
}

@end

@implementation Location
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your  `Screen2ViewController.h`:

```
@interface Screen2ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MapTableProtocol> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

Your `MKMapView` from interface builder is probably linked to the `@property`, but everywhere in the `Screen2ViewController.m` you are working with `mapView` (instance variable which is never initialised) instead of `self.mapView`.

---

Also, compared to `Screen5ViewController.m` you are missing `MapTable` initialisation in `Screen2ViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
_mapTable = [[MapTable alloc] init];
```

Comment: I have removed all of the mapview code from my project, but Screen2ViewController still never calls the MapTable.m method. So it doesnt look like the problem is anything to do with any mapview code.

Comment: That's it! I was missing the [MapTable alloc] in my second viewcontroller. I really cant believe I missed that! I have spent days and days going over the code and never spotted that. Thank you so much for pointing this out!!